# How to read chunks of multiple large CSV files from google cloud storage using Dask without overloading the memory all at once

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to read a bunch of large csv files (multiple files) from google storage. I use the **Dask** distribution library for parallel computation, but the problem I'm facing here is, though I mention the **blocksize (100mb)**, I'm not sure how to read partition by partition and save it to my **postgres** database so that I don't want overload my memory.

```
    from dask.distributed import Client
    from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
    client = Client(processes=False)
    import dask.dataframe as dd

    def read_csv_gcs():
      with ProgressBar():
        df = dd.read_csv('gs://mybucket/renish/*.csv', blocksize=100e6)
        pd = df.compute(scheduler='threads')
        return pd

    def write_df_to_db(df):
      try:
        from sqlalchemy import create_engine
        engine = create_engine('postgresql://usr:pass@localhost:5432/sampledb')
        df.to_sql('sampletable', engine, if_exists='replace',index=False)
      except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass

    pd = read_csv_gcs()
    write_df_to_db(pd)
```

The above code is my basic implementation, but as said I would like to read it in chunk and update the db. Something like

```
    df = dd.read_csv('gs://mybucket/renish/*.csv', blocksize=100e6)
    for chunk in df:
       write_it_to_db(chunk)
```

Is it possible to do it in **Dask?** or should I go for pandas's chunksize and iterate, then save it to DB (But I miss parallel computation here)?

Can someone shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
df.compute(scheduler='threads')
```

says: load the data in chunks in worker threads, and concatenate them all into a single in-memory dataframe, `df`. This is not what you wanted. You wanted to insert the chunks as they come and then *drop them from memory*.

You probably wanted to use `map_partitions`

```
df = dd.read_csv('gs://mybucket/renish/*.csv', blocksize=100e6)
df.map_partitions(write_it_to_db).compute()
```

or use `df.to_delayed()`.

Note that, depending on your SQL driver, you might not be able to get parallelism this way, and if not, the pandas iter-chunk method would have worked just as well.

Comment: Thank you, so should I use like df.to_delayed(write_it_to_db), believing it will drop them from memory or we should use both map_partitions & to_delayed?

Comment: map_partitions and to_delayed and mutually exclusive options here - please read the documentation for delayed.